# How to track a Java bug?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

i'm a React/PHP/Javascript developer who is recently learning java, and a bug appeared, and i have been stuck trying to track it or change it.
It is related to Hibernate, but i want to know that if by the stackTrace i am able to track the exact function:
Below there is an image of the **stackTrace**, and i will add it as text too.

[image: StackTrace]
    The **stackTrace** has been added as text below, **there is more and i can add it if needed**

```
  Dica: There is a column named "fgtype" in table "*SELECT* 1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
  Posição: 66079
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 182 common frames omitted
```

**Any help to move forward would be appreciated.**

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug in Hibernate not in your code?

Comment: not really sure... any help would be welcome, i can show more code if needed

Comment: Please do so. If you are beginner, then it would be problem with your code most of the time, not with library.

Comment: You should attach the code of the query

Comment: @PradeepSimha  `related to hibranate` != `it's a bug in Hibrenate` and I don't think OP meant to say that.

Comment: I'm not being able to find the query through the full stackTrace.